returning entity model property with extra string
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API using Dapper as ORM.
This is my entity class:
namespace Server.Entities
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Title { get; set; } 
        public string Slug { get; set; } 
        public int CategoryId { get; set; } 
        public bool Bookmarked = false;
        public bool Liked = false;
        public bool Premium { get; set; }
        public string BriefText { get; set; } 
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string CoverImage { get; set; } 
        public int ReadingTime { get; set; }
        public Collection<string> Tags = new Collection<string>();
        public int Author { get; set; } 
        public Collection<Post> Relateds = new Collection<Post>();
        public Collection<Comment> Comments = new Collection<Comment>();
    }

    public class PostDTO
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        public string CoverImage { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}

Here's my controller:
 [HttpGet]
 public async Task<ActionResult> GetAllPosts()
 {
    PostDTO[] posts = await _dbContext.Post.GetAllAsync();
    return Ok(posts);
 }

And my service:
 public async Task<PostDTO[]> GetAllAsync()
 {
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Posts";
    IEnumerable<PostDTO> posts = await _connection.QueryAsync<PostDTO>(query);
    return posts.ToArray();
 }

As you see I return PostDTO to the client, the CoverImage property is an image URL without domain name, like this:
 /uploads/coverImage/2024/7/10/1723272284733-718853888.jpg

For using this url in frontend, I have to add the domain before the URL. Is there any way to combine the domain automatically with the property before sending it to client?
I used this:
public class PostDTO
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    public string CoverImage { get; set; }
    public string CoverImageURL
    {
        get => "http://localhost:8000" + CoverImage;
        set => CoverImage = value;
    }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

This way I would have a full image URL, but I think it's not a good idea to return an extra property to client.
What if I modify the main property CoverImage to return the full URL as shown here:
public class PostDTO
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    public string CoverImage
    {
        get => "http://localhost:8000" + CoverImage;
        set => CoverImage = value;
    }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

Using this, I get an error from Dapper:

info:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[102]
Route matched with {action = "GetAllPosts", controller = "Post"}. Executing controller action with signature
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult]
GetAllPosts() on controller Server.Controllers.PostController
(server). Stack overflow. Repeat 24234 times:
at Server.Entities.PostDTO.set_CoverImage(System.String)
at DynamicClass.Deserializedeb5d960-6b33-4fce-84f4-e8ee01aaac3a(System.Data.Common.DbDataReader)
at Dapper.SqlMapper+d__331[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1+AsyncStateMachineBox1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Dapper.SqlMapper+<QueryAsync>d__331[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Dapper, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1+AsyncStateMachineBox1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e], Dapper.SqlMapper+d__331[[System.__Canon,  System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Dapper, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1+AsyncStateMachineBox1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e], Dapper.SqlMapper+<QueryAsync>d__331[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Dapper, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishSlow(Boolean)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef, System.Threading.Thread)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryRunInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuation.InlineIfPossibleOrElseQueue(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinueWithTaskContinuation.Run(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)     at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetFromTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ProcessInnerTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishSlow(Boolean)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef, System.Threading.Thread)
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool+WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()


You should not return entities to clients. I recommend to map your entities to dto's (data transfer objects). This method has multiple advantages, e.g. your clients are not affected when you change your data layer and with that your entities. Furthermore you would be able to put the domain to the url within the mapping. You can find more information about dto's here: https://medium.com/@samuelcatalano/best-practices-for-data-transfer-objects-dtos-d5007e3f2729
I am using AutoMapper to map the objects: https://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper/

If there is no need for CoverImage in your response object and only property of value is the full URL, then only have the CoverImageUrl field in the DTO and remove CoverImage. Only return whats needed.
Populate CoverImageUrl in your mappings when mapping the entity to the DTO. If you have a service class or similar that receives the entity and maps it to the DTO you can concat the values there.
There should be no logic in a DTO, only flat data in my humble opinion.

You can make CoverImage a private property then remove  set for CoverImageURL.  Dapper can then set the CoverImage and the sterilizationi can read the combined field.

@Nope You are saying I should write multiple codes in my service class to convert my entity class to a DTO as I need? for example I should use foreach and iterate my list came from server to convert one by one data to DTO? is it a right way?

Not at all what I said @Reza245 - You already have a DTO and you always map  it which ever you do. I said that instead of having concatonation inside the DTO to do the concatonation in the code that you map from the entity to the DTO.
Having logic in the DTO is usually bad as DTOs should be flat and only contain the properties you actually intent to return.
Having the logic inside the DTO instead of the code that maps the entity to the DTO also means you now have to write a unit test against your DTO instead of your mapping code.
Just personal preference :)

This SO issue is related with the CoverImage set method call itself which caused this issue.
To solve this issue, I suggest you could write a new property which will create the full local string.
More details, you could refer to below example:
PostDTO:
public class PostDTO
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }

  
    private string _coverImage;

 
    public string CoverImage
    {
        get => _coverImage;
        set => _coverImage = value;
    }

     public string FullCoverImageURL
    {
        get => "http://localhost:8000" + _coverImage;
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}

Usage:
        var connectionString = @"xx";

        using var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Posts";
        IEnumerable<PostDTO> posts =   conn.Query<PostDTO>(query);
        var result= posts.ToArray();

        return Ok(result);

Result:


